How do I check if a macro was run before proceeding with a different macro?
I am learning VBA and attempting to automate a report that has multiple steps.
Step 1 - Click Button #1 to run a macro with a series of formulas based on input data provided by the user.
Step 2 - Click Button #2 to perform calculations based off the results of Step 1.
Step 3 - Click Button #3 to perform the 3rd and final round of calculations.
Step 4 - Click Button #4 to format the worksheets (paste as values, conditional formatting, etc.).
Step 5 - Save the file as a new Excel workbook with a title based off of input data provided by the user.
Each set of calculations (Steps 1-3) pulls data in from a different software provider and can take 1-3 minutes to populate. Since the calculation time varies, I opted to create the multi-step process so the user can be sure the calculations are complete. However, I want to ensure that the user follows the process in order.  How do I stop Macro2 from running if the user hasn't run Macro1 first...and so on?
Thank you in advance for your time.
I tried to play around with Select Case, but admittedly, I do not understand what the code is attempting to do.

Deactivate all but button one by default. Then have each macro disable all buttons except the button for the next step.

Or create a sheet to log each step. Macro 1 should start a new row with a datetime value. The other macros must make sure the most recent session has rows for the previous steps before starting. Otherwise msgbox "You must complete the previous step before performing this step".

Do you mind giving me an example of the code to create the table?

Should the user be able to go back and re-run steps 1 or 2 ?

Marking this as subjective (outside of SO scope), due to not having an objective answer, e.g., correcting an issue with your existing script.  Additionally, I will give my input regarding a solution a user requested I build in the past (worked for his purpose):  1) We created a table with radio buttons that autoadvance when a macro is run; 2) we have a button to run each macro to the right of the radio button/description that can only be activated if the associated radio button has a true value; 3) when all steps are completed a pop-up occurs indicating the full process has been run.

(ran out of space)... Using the radio buttons, a user was able to go back and select a different step to re-run or restart a process if they screwed up.  That also meant that removing data and capturing that information was required.  We hid data in the cell behind the macro buttons so we were not reliant on global variables that go away if closed.

Add a new sheet to the end of your workbook named Log. Create these 2 functions:
Sub AddLogRow(strStep As String)
    'Add a row to the Log sheet with the date, step , and user info 
    NextFreeRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Log").Rows(NextFreeRow).Cells(1) = Now()
    Sheets("Log").Rows(NextFreeRow).Cells(2) = strStep
    Sheets("Log").Rows(NextFreeRow).Cells(3) = Application.UserName
End Sub

Function LastStep() As String
    'Return the last step in the Log sheet
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastStep = Sheets("Log").Rows(LastRow).Cells(2)
End Function

Your macros can now start by checking if LastStep returns the previous step.
When a macro ends have it call AddLogRow("step name")
The advantage of this strategy is a log of user and step events. You can redo an event by first editing the log. For extra credit hide the Log sheet for admin use only.

In a convenient location or a new tab, set up 3 ranges, Macro1, Macro2, and Macro3.  Then at the end of the code for each macro, include the statement
Range("Macro<1 2 or 3>") = Now()

Add Labels around those ranges to indicate which macro they refer to, and the tag "Last Run".
